# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code MAC,iOS, FLUTTER Project

Tags: flutter

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[87725]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x21058e7a0) and ?? (0x116cac2b8). One
of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[87725]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x21058e7f0) and ?? (0x116cac308). One of the two
will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6.3/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:273:2
1: Error: The method 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'
('../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType'.
return context?.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(SmartRefresher);

Flutter Doctor Output
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.83, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 2.1.0-11.0.pre.83 at /Users/bijuyohannan/development/flutter
• Framework revision dff42b8ee1 (3 weeks ago), 2021-03-03 03:14:02 -0500
• Engine revision cd0e54348b
• Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-93.0.dev)

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
`flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
• CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
• Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 9EDD473E-DECC-4648-9F22-9283ECE9867B • ios            •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
• Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90

Comment: Did you find any solution?